# windows credential provider remote logon

Tags: c++, remote-access, smartcard, credential-providers

I am trying to read a credential from a smart card on one workstation (local), then send it to a different workstation(remote) and use it to logon to that workstation from within a credential provider.

I've been searching and, and researching for weeks now but have not found anyone showing or telling how to do this.

I have found several references to an excellent work at https://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/LsaSmartCardLogon2.cpp, which is working code for a smart card credential provider, but unfortunately requires that the credential provider have direct access to the smart card with the credential on it.

The actual code I am working with seems a little to long to include in the post so I thought I try asking the question using sudo code. 
On the local workstation:

```
MySendCredentialsFromSmartCard(){
    CryptAcquireContext(hProv, containerName, cardName, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_SILENT) 
    CryptGetUserKey(*hProv, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, &hCryptKey); 
    CryptGetKeyParam(hCryptKey, KP_CERTIFICATE, encodedCert, &size, 0); 
    MySendCertToRemote(encodedCert,size); 
}
```

On Remote workstation running in custom credential provider:

```
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSerialization( 
    _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr, 
    _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcs, 
    _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PWSTR *ppwszOptionalStatusText, 
    _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon){ 

    MyReadCertFromRemote(&cert,&size); 
    CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0); 
    CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA1, NULL, 0, &hHash); 
    CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE *)cert, (DWORD)size, 0); 

    CERT_CREDENTIAL_INFO certInfo; 

    CryptGetHashParam(hHash, HP_HASHVAL, certInfo.rgbHashOfCert, &dwHashLen, 0); 
    CredMarshalCredential(CertCredential, &certInfo, marshalledCred); 
/****************************for debug only*****************************/ 
    LogonUser((*marshalledCred, NULL, NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &userHandle); 
//this reuturns 1 (success) 
/**************************************************************************/ 
    KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON kiul; 
    CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus 
    KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit(L"", (PWSTR)marshaledCred, L"", cpus, &kiul);//(note:I've tried this with the third param set to the card's pin) 
    KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack(kiul, &pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &pcpcs->cbSerialization); 
    RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(&ulAuthPackage); 
    pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage; 
    pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_OfProvider; 
    *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED; 
}
```

LogonUI.exe displays "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." This seams to correspond to Windows error code 1312. It seems that most developers struggling with this error code are having trouble configuring IIS with an SSL cert. I have found no reference to this error in relation to a credential provider. 
Various threads seem to indicate that LogonUser is mearly a wrapper around LSALogonUser and the returned values from ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization will be passed to LSALogonUser. The fact that my call to LogonUser with the marshalled credential succeeds would seem to suggest that on I'm on the right track, but I haven't been able to verify that nor figure out what I'm missing. 
I would like to try to avoid solutions that require storing the credential on the remote workstation as it is typically a domain admin credential. 
Any ideas anybody? Any advise on how to proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it using a communication mechanism where you send your data from one workstation to another one and in the remote one you serialize your data in SetSerialization() instead of GetSerialization(), preparing all the fields and processing the logon.

From my understanding point of you, the Provider class (the one inherited by ICredentialProvider) has to wait for those credentials somehow and pass them to SetSerialization